# undefined method `as_name' in rubykoan

Tags: ruby

I'm doing [RubyKoan](http://rubykoans.com/) `about_iteration` part.
But, I encounter an error on the `test_each_is_a_method_on_arrays` test that I don't know how to solve ;

```
undefined method `as_name' for #<AboutIteration:0x00007fcbc6031dc8 @name=:test_each_is_a_method_on_arrays, 
@failure=#<NoMethodError: undefined method `as_name' for #<AboutIteration:0x00007fcbc6031dc8 ...>>, @koan_cou
nt=17, @step_count=158, @koan_file="AboutIteration">
```

This is the code ;

```rb
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/neo')

class AboutIteration < Neo::Koan

  # -- An Aside ------------------------------------------------------
  # Ruby 1.8 stores names as strings. Ruby 1.9 stores names as
  # symbols. So we use a version dependent method "as_name" to convert
  # to the right format in the koans.  We will use "as_name" whenever
  # comparing to lists of methods.

  in_ruby_version("1.8") do
    def as_name(name)
      name.to_s
    end
  end

  in_ruby_version("1.9", "2.0") do
    def as_name(name)
      name.to_sym
    end
  end

  # Ok, now back to the Koans.
  # -------------------------------------------------------------------

  def test_each_is_a_method_on_arrays
    assert_equal true, [].methods.include?(as_name(:each))
  end
```

This is the full error ;

```
➜  koans git:(main) ✗ ruby path_to_enlightenment.rb
AboutIteration#test_each_is_a_method_on_arrays has damaged your karma.

The Master says:
  You have not yet reached enlightenment.
  Do not lose hope.

The answers you seek...
  undefined method `as_name' for #<AboutIteration:0x00007fcbc6031dc8 @name=:test_each_is_a_method_on_arrays, 
@failure=#<NoMethodError: undefined method `as_name' for #<AboutIteration:0x00007fcbc6031dc8 ...>>, @koan_cou
nt=17, @step_count=158, @koan_file="AboutIteration">

Please meditate on the following code:
  /Users/amirulasyraf/Documents/koans/about_iteration.rb:27:in `test_each_is_a_method_on_arrays'

when you lose, don't lose the lesson
your path thus far [............................X_____________________] 157/278 (56%)
```

Answer (score 4):

You are using a version of RubyKoans that is **over seven years out-of-date** and only supports Ruby 1.8, 1.9, and 2.0. The current version of RubyKoans supports Ruby up to 2.7 (but not 3.0).

Comment: Oh, I see. Haha. Do you know how I can get back to Ruby 2.7, cuz right now I already upgrade it to 3.0.

Comment: That...sucks. Just installed Ruby, went directly from the website to the Koans (http://rubykoans.com/windows) and now that I'm half way through I find out I'm 7 years behind. Ok then. lol. :(

Answer (score 1):

`#as_name` is defined in the `in_ruby_version` block. Adding Ruby 3 to the list of versions did it for me.

```rb
 in_ruby_version("1.9", "2", "3") do
    def as_name(name)
      name.to_sym
    end
  end
```

Comment: Thank you. Moving forward!